# insertion sort algorithm pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode, sorting

```
INSERTION-SORT(A)
1 for j ← 2 to length[A]
2   do key ← A[j]
3     ▹ Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1  j - 1].
4     i ← j - 1
5     while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6     do A[i + 1] ← A[i]
7         i ← i - 1
8     A[i + 1] ← key
```

Hi! this is my first question.Could anyone help me understand this code? why is it 'A[i+1]=A[i]'? shouldn't this be other way round as we are going down the list.

Comment: Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Answer (score 1):

`A[i+1]=A[i]` is used to shift each element greater than `key` one place to the right, so that we can put `key` before them.

You can find more information on this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: Thanks!
alright that means each element is shifted until the loop condition in line 5 becomes 'false'.
The line element is then inserted in line 8 right?